# Extract date from time series object in R

Tags: r

I have a data consisting of 4 variable viz., Date, Gold price, Crude oil price and Dollar in Rs. as shown below.

```
head(Gold)

        DATE       GOLD.PRICE  CRUDE   DOLLAR.INR
     1 2006-01-04      533.9  63.42     44.705
     2 2006-01-05      526.3  62.79     44.600
     3 2006-01-06      539.7  64.21     44.320
     4 2006-01-09      549.1  63.50     44.250
     5 2006-01-10      544.3  63.37     44.185
     6 2006-01-11      548.8  63.94     43.915
```

Here is my data.

```
Gold <- structure(list(DATE = structure(c(13152, 13153, 13154, 13157, 
13158, 13159), class = "Date"), GOLD.PRICE = c(533.9, 526.3, 
539.7, 549.1, 544.3, 548.8), CRUDE = c(63.42, 62.79, 64.21, 63.5, 
63.37, 63.94), DOLLAR.INR = c(44.705, 44.6, 44.32, 44.25, 44.185, 
43.915)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("DATE", "GOLD.PRICE", 
"CRUDE", "DOLLAR.INR"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

I want to perform time series analysis, so I convert my data frame object to time series object.

```
 Gold.ts <- ts(Gold,start=1)
 head(Gold.ts)
    DATE GOLD.PRICE CRUDE DOLLAR.INR

 [1,] 13152      533.9 63.42     44.705
 [2,] 13153      526.3 62.79     44.600
 [3,] 13154      539.7 64.21     44.320
 [4,] 13157      549.1 63.50     44.250
 [5,] 13158      544.3 63.37     44.185
 [6,] 13159      548.8 63.94     43.915
```

Now how do I understand the date corresponding to each record? How do I extract date after converting to time series object?

Comment: Try with `xts` i.e. `library(xts); xts(Gold[-1], order.by = as.Date(Gold[,1]))`

Comment: @akrun- I am able to get date even after converting to xts object. Is it possible to perform vector autoregressive model using the xts object?

Comment: I don't know your codes.  Without that I cannot comment

Comment: I created the data called Gold using dput().

Answer (score 1):

You can use the zoo library.

```
library(zoo)
as.yearmon(time(Gold.ts))
```

You will get the following result:

> [1] "Jan 0001" "Jan 0002" "Jan 0003" "Jan 0004" "Jan 0005" "Jan 0006"